# How to lint entire folder using tslint

Tags: typescript, tslint

Is that possible to lint entire folder using tslint?

Using eslint it is possible to do `eslint ./src` to validate whole folder.

When i try to do the same for tslint - i am getting an error `Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory`. In their examples on the site - they show how to validate single file, which is not the case usually.

Is that possible to validate my project without extra things like `gulp-tslint`, just from the command line?

Comment: Figured it out, that its possible to use wildcards - `tslint src/**/*.ts`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was wondering how exactly to use wildcards.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can use a glob to lint multiple files.

Normally, if you just pass a glob as is, your shell will expand it and pass the resulting files to TSLint. So for example, in bash 4+ with the globstar option enabled, you could do the following to lint all `.ts` and `.tsx` files:

```
tslint src/**/*.ts{,x}
```

You're probably better off though using a command that will work consistently across platforms and shells though. For this, you can pass the glob in quotes. When in quotes, the glob will get passed as is to TSLint which will handle it with [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob). You could then run the following command to get the same results as above:

```
tslint 'src/**/*.ts?(x)'
```

Comment: Indeed, it seems like no-quotes only works on Windows. Thanks!

Comment: so this does not work if I have a file a direct child of src.
say src/index.ts, which is a common use case I suppose

Comment: @HaroonKhan both should work. I'm assuming in your case you were using the bash version of the glob. You likely [did not have the globstar option set](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156808/275542). Try switching to quoted version to take advantage of node-glob, which also has the nice side-effect of making your script more platform-independent

Comment: worked like a charm, but now failing in `lint-staged` :) will have a look at it ina while

Comment: helpful! [for those unfamiliar with what a glob is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))

Comment: 2¢, fwiw, the quoted one did _not_ work on a DOS prompt, but did in Powershell. Without quotes _only_ works on DOS, not Powershell. (Re: *a command that will work consistently across platforms and shells*)

Answer (score 29):

There is now a `--project` option for this. Example:

```
tslint --project .
```

From the [docs](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/cli/):

> -p, --project:
>
> The path or directory containing a tsconfig.json file that will be
>      used to determine which files will be linted. This flag also enables
>      rules that require the type checker.

Comment: This works :) Thank you. The other wild card method wasn't finding all of the files.

Comment: I don't really understand the --project argument. Do you know how can I exclude files?

Comment: The --project argument simply tells it to use the settings in the tsconfig.json file. So if you want to exclude files you'd need to configure that in tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 11):

> **If your project has a tsconfig.json you can aproach --project advange.**

In my case I have a nativescript project wich includes a `tsconfig.json` at project root, so I have this:

[image]

Note that in the json 'node_modules' and 'platforms' directories are excluded. **This means that all files in the project are going to be mapped except 'node_modules' and 'platforms' directories.**

I have added this scripts at my package.json, 'tslint' to log the errors and 'tslint-fix' to fix the errors.

```js
"scripts": {
    "tslint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json",
    "tslint-fix": "tslint --fix -p tsconfig.json"
}
```