# Auto fix TSLint Warnings

Tags: angular, typescript, warnings, tslint

```
    [64, 1]: space indentation expected
    [15, 27]: Missing semicolon
    [109, 36]: missing whitespace
    [111, 24]: missing whitespace
    [70, 1]: Consecutive blank lines are forbidden
```

I keep getting warnings like these  from TSLint. There are huge amount of warnings, and it will be very difficult to fix it manually.

I was looking for a way which can **auto-fix** most of the warnings.

Comment: this answer may be usefull: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36447910/how-to-lint-entire-folder-using-tslint/50399684#50399684

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You can use the [`--fix` option](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/cli/#cli-usage) of TSLint to automatically fix most warnings. This might look something like this in a common use case:

```
tslint --fix -c ./config/tslint.json 'src/**/*{.ts,.tsx}'
```

Keep in mind that this will overwrite your source code. While this is safe 99.9% of the time, I recommend the following workflow:

1. Commit the changes you have made to your code
2. Run TSLint with the `--fix` flag like above
3. Quickly review the changes TSLint has made
4. Make a new commit with these changes, or simply amend them to your previous commit

This way, you'll never be taken surprise by a rogue autocorrection gone wrong.

Comment: If you are using Angular CLI, this is run using ```ng lint --fix```

Comment: @daniel.caspers or `node_modules\.bin\tslint --fix -c ./tslint.json 'src/**/*{.ts,.tsx}'`

Answer (score 24):

```
tslint --fix --project ./tsconfig.json
```

This is auto fix all Error is root folder

Answer (score 13):

With @angular/cli you can use `ng lint --fix`

Answer (score 9):

May be this could help some one looking for autoFix on save!

we can make tslint warnings to get autofixed on save. To do this, go to tslint.json file and add the below settings. **[Note: This setting works with latest TSLint and not the deprecated one].**

```
  "source.fixAll.tslint": true
```

After updating this, go to any file and try giving some spaces and it shows tslint warning message as "trailing whitespace" and when you save (Ctrl + S), this warning will get disappear. Though it appears manually, we usually tend to try saving the file once edited and by that time it will get fixed automatically.

Happy coding!

Comment: Amazing! One thing: you have to add the line to `settings.json` and not tslint.json. Full code to add: `"editor.codeActionsOnSave": { "source.fixAll.tslint": true }`

Answer (score 4):

If you using **IntelliJ Idea** or **WebStrom**, then you can create File Watcher in *Settings > Tools* by the following configuration:

[image]

On save (**Ctrl + s**), your current file will be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

If you using webpack . You can use tslint-loader:

Add this to webpack module rules:

```
{
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loader: 'tslint-loader',
    enforce: 'pre',
    options: {
      fix: true
    }
  }
```

Read more here: [tslint-loader](https://github.com/wbuchwalter/tslint-loader)