# Move .tsconfig and .tslint file to different directory

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint, tsconfig, linter

Inside my Angular CLI project I want to move all my config files into a new folder which I've named 'angular'. The code compiles and all npm scripts run, but I'm not getting any linting or typescript errors inside my `app` folder. Here is the folder structure I am attempting:

```
 project
    │   tslint.config.json
    │   tslint.json    
    │
    └───src
         │   
         └───angular
         │   tsconfig.app.json
         │   tslint.json
         │     
         └───app
              │   app.module.ts
              │   app.component.ts
```

All references inside of my angular.json file have been updated and there are no errors, but the only place the linter works is INSIDE of the 'angular' folder! How can I change this to point to my 'app' folder?
The reason I want to do this customization is to keep the files I hardly ever use out of view like this:

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to move those files in the first place? It goes against the code standards.

Comment: Because it looks much cleaner in my folder structure and helps me stay focused on my app folder, hiding all the files I hardly ever use out of view.

Comment: This could probably help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36447910/how-to-lint-entire-folder-using-tslint

Answer (score 4):

Based on the image of your directory structure, I'm assume that you're trying to configure VS Code specifically to give you syntax highlighting?

If so, you can create a workspace specific configuration for your project, explicitly defining where VS Code can find a tslint.json configuration. By default VS Code will look at the root of your project for your tslint configuration. In order to set your own workspace configuration you can follow the instructions from the [VS Code Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings). On my mac I select the following menu items:

> Code -> Preferences -> Settings

From there I select:

> the "Workspace Settings" tab and Extensions -> TSLint from the Workspace Settings sidebar

There is a property for Config File where you can set the path to your TSLint Configuration, relative to the root of the project. For you this would be "./src/angular/tslint.json"

[image: TSLint Config File location]

In order to get console output of tslint for your project you would have to explicitly define where your tslint and tsconfig configuration files exist since they're not in the root of your project:

```
tslint -c src/angular/tslint.json -p src/angular/tsconfig.json
```

*I believe* VS Code is configured to use the locally installed version of Typescript by default, based on the version installed in your node_modules/typescript directory. Because of this, you will continue to receive feedback on your typescript errors based on your local typescript installation, or alternatively a globally installed version of typescript.

The typescript documentation states that:

> The presence of a tsconfig.json file in a directory indicates that the directory is **the root of a TypeScript project**.

So moving your tsconfig.json anywhere but the root of the project would go against the intended nature of your typescript configuration, however you can still compile you code if your tsconfig.json is not located at the root of the project by calling (or creating an npm script do the same):

```
tsc --project ./src/angular/tsconfig.json
```

Assuming you have an "include" definition in your tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* your compiler options */
  },
  "include": [
    // source code for project is one directory up from tsconfig.json
    "../**/*",
  ]
}
```